# Unable to retrieve entire contents of Cursor due to CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException (to put into jagged array of strings)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to get the contents of a cursor and put them into a 2d string for usage later in my app. To do this, I've written the following function:

```
public String[][] cursorTo2dString (Cursor cursor) {

    int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    String[][] string2dArray = new String[count][columnCount];
    Log.i("StringLengths", count + " & " + columnCount);
    Log.i("CursorConts", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        for (int j=0; j<count && !cursor.isAfterLast(); j++)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<columnCount; i++)
            {
                Log.i("Cursor", cursor.getString(i));
                string2dArray[j][i] = cursor.getString(i);
                Log.i("StringPoint", string2dArray[j][i]);
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    return string2dArray;
}
```

This is giving me the following results in the console when the program crashes

```
I/StringLengths: 1 & 2
I/CursorConts: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@f7e2e6f
               0 {
                  TagIdNo=3866
                  TagName=No Parental Permission
               }
               <<<<<
I/Cursor: 3866
I/StringPoint: 3866
I/Cursor: No Parental Permission
I/StringPoint: No Parental Permission
I/MovePos: true & false
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.programming.workingpomproject, PID: 29771
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
                   Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
                      at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                      at com.example.programming.workingpomproject.DbHelper.cursorTo2dString(DbHelper.java:155)
                      at com.example.programming.workingpomproject.DbHelper.select(DbHelper.java:89)
                      at com.example.programming.workingpomproject.DbHelper.select(DbHelper.java:92)
                      at com.example.programming.workingpomproject.MainActivity.testDbMethodGet(MainActivity.java:66)
                      at com.example.programming.workingpomproject.MainActivity.dbStuff(MainActivity.java:61)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Any advice as to how to resolve this, and any amendments to my method, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any and all help! I apologise for any issues with my coding standards, this is my first android app and my first time in Java, though I've written in C# before.

***Edit1:***

The exception thus far is appearing on the line

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) //line 117
```

or at least this is the line that is highlighted by Android Studio's debugger. I suspect that the exception isn't in fact occurring here because this line number is 117 and the if statement ends on line 129, neither of which actually appear in the debugger; also, the program flow is jumping straight to here from the line

```
Log.i("Cursor", cursor.getString(i)); //line 123
```

once i is equal to 2 whilst j is equal to 0. This is shown by the fact that  the breakpoints I leave on the two following lines go untriggered in this iteration of the inner loop.

I've amended the code section above to show the current situation. These amendments consist of removing the last two Log.i statements that existed before. These were as follows

```
Log.i("MovePos", String.valueOf(cursor.isAfterLast()) + " & " + cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getColumnIndex("TagName")));
    Log.i("LOOK HERE", cursor.getString(0));
```

Which never got ran anyhow according to the console log.

Comment: what do you need that 2d array for? for some list view adapter?

Comment: I want to use the array to hold the results of queries because I'm having trouble pacing through cursors. I want to retrieve the query from a database storing a bunch of tags that will be associated with services, in an app being used to promote mental health services.

I'm currently using a random tagIdNo value generated differently for each time the button that triggers this test is pressed, and the tag "No parental permission" would be used for services where there is no legal requirement for parental permission for an appointment. Thanks for your help, pskink!

Comment: so use `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {...` pattern, but if it is to be passed to some adapter, then just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: Could you post that as an answer so I can handle it as such? I tried this method before to no avail, but I'll try it and document the results for the thread. Thanks!

Comment: Tell us what line is the Exception taking place and delete those last 2 logs. Then report back.

Comment: I've done so in the Edit1 section of the question. The changes seemed to have no influence on how the code ran, but some interesting notes on the program flow arose from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
public String[][] makeArrayFromCursor(Cursor csr) {

       String[][] rv = new String[csr.getCount()][csr.getColumnCount()];
       if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
           int called_pos = csr.getPosition();
           csr.moveToPosition(-1);
           while (csr.moveToNext()) {
               for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                   rv[csr.getPosition()][i] = csr.getString(i);
               }
           }
           csr.moveToPosition(called_pos);
       }

       return rv;
   }
```

Notes

- will return String array of nulls if the cursor is empty.
- will reposition cursor to it's original position whatever that was via `called_pos`.
- moving to -1 is before the first row (again just in case cursor had been used and had been positioned elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks. I found just today that my code worked okay now, but only if the cursor returns more than one record. Thoughts? I'll try this with one record and see how it goes too.
Thanks for your help! Also, good practice with the notes. Didn't think of re-positioning the cursor but I really should if I use this as a method, like I am doing. Thanks for the idea!